# CameraX only landscape

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am using sample Android project => https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraXBasic.

I modified `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in `Manifest.xml` in order to work only in landscape mode. I also removed below line `android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"`

if I hold the phone in portrait, I want to see it as in landspace.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your activity's `onCreate` :
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)`